# Getting deadlocks on MS SQL stored procedure performing a read/update (put code to handle deadlocks)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, deadlock

I have to admit I'm just learning about properly handling deadlocks but based on suggestions I read, I thought this was the proper way to handle it.  Basically I have many processes trying to 'reserve' a row in the database for an update.  So I first read for an available row, then write to it.  Is this not the right way?  If so, how do I need to fix this SP?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[reserveAccount] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @machineId varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    declare @id BIGINT;

    set @id = (select min(id) from Account_Data where passfail is null and reservedby is null);

    update Account_data set reservedby = @machineId where ID = @id;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write this as a single statement.  That will may fix the update problem:

```
update Account_data
    set reservedby = @machineId
    where ID = (select min(id) from Account_Data where passfail is null and reservedby is null);
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think about the fact that it could and should be combined into one statement like that.  Thank you very much.

Comment: So over the past few days, I have been trying this out and seeing the same amount of deadlocks happening.  What am I missing here that is causing so many deadlocks when this SP is getting called by a lot of processes?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This pattern like the original pattern in the question does not prevent race conditions. It is possible for two concurrent sessions to get the same ID and proceed with the update. 

Capture and post a deadlock XML for better analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yur problem is 2that you have 2 statements - a select and an update. if those run concurrent, then the select will..... make a read lock and the update will demand a write lock. At the same time 2 machins deadlock.

Simple solution is to make the initial select demand an uddate lock (WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK) as hint). That may or may not work (depends on what else goes on) but it is a good start.

Second step - if that fails - is to use an application elvel lock (sp_getapplock) that makes sure a critical system always has only one owner and htus only exeutes transactions serially.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I guess I misunderstood.  I was under the assumption that setting my isolation level would do what you mentioned above, locking the read row, so that I can update it without any conflicts.

Comment: No. Or - it depends. Anything except tx level serializable will not. And you do not set a particularly good isolation level. ReadCommited makes sure exactly that what I say happens.

Comment: @TomTom Under Read Committed Isolation Level, the reads does not hold the Shared locks until the end of the transaction. So the read lock will be released by the time of the update lock request.